# aligning text and box horizontally using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.floating-box{
 display:inline-block;
 height:10px;
 margin:20px;
 
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=floating-box style="display:inline-block;"> 
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="100" height="103" style="border:1px solid black;margin-right:170px">
 <script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,103);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 103);
ctx.stroke();

</script>
</canvas>
<div class="floating-box"><h2>Product Name </h2></div>
</div>
```

guys what i want is to align the box and the text horizontally ... by the way i am totally newbie .. so please help me :)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Replace canvas tag with this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="100" height="103" style="border:1px solid black;display: -webkit-inline-box;border: 1px solid black;margin-right: 0px;">
```

Comment: still not yet aligned

Comment: You wanted horizontally align na?

Comment: yes ... to put the text horizontal with the top of the box

Comment: In that case use this css-- : h2{margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;}

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box concept to achieve this easily. Refer to this [Cheat Sheet](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) for customisation.

```css
.floating-box{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: flex-start;
 align-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: center;
}

h2 { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class=floating-box style=""> 
  <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="100" height="103" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
 
  <div class="name"><h2>Product Name </h2></div>

</div>

<script>
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(100,103);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 103);
      ctx.stroke();
  </script>
```

Comment: what if i want the text to be aligned with the top horizontal line of the box ?

Comment: You can use `align-items: flex-start` and set the default margin of h2 to 0